# Testing a hypothesis with one measurement

Tags: hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval

I accept as a fact that it is not possible to "accept" a hypothesis , but merely "not rejecting" it.

Then, for the sake of my argument, let's say we have a hypothesis that predicts that variable A is normally distributed, with mean zero and standard deviation one.

We are the first team in world history to be able to actually measure A. But we can measure it only once.

How much, and why, should the value of our unique measurement be far from zero, for you to seriously doubt the validity of our hypothesis (i.e. reject it ) ?

(Maybe some well thought r simulation could help ?)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What sort of alternatives did you have in mind? If a competing theory predicts that $A$ has a Cauchy distribution with location $0$ and scale $\frac{1}{10}$, then a single observation of $A$ close to zero might count against your theory as much as one far from zero. But if, as you seem to imply, you're happy to take $|A|$ as a measure of the observation's discrepancy with your theory, then what's the problem? Standard normal tables give the tail-area probabilities.

Comment: @Scortchi I understand your point. But yes, Cauchy distribution aside, I am happy to think of that observation in term of its ability to help us reject or not reject the postulated theory. Is there anything wrong with such way of thinking ?

Comment: Using $|A|$ as a test statistic gives power against location-shift alternatives - it's equivalent to the likelihood-ratio test for a normal mean - as well as against the broad, non-directional, classes of alternative usually considered when evaluating goodness-of-fit tests - it's equivalent to the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test. Is it that you've a test in mind that you'd use with more observations, but doubt its applicability in the single-observation case?

Comment: Maybe what I have in mind is whether it is possible or not to reject a theory, given one observation ? (e.g. when that observation (among a set of only one observation) is improbable enough under one's personal standards (or community's consensus standards))

Comment: Well, distinguish between rejecting a statistical hypothesis & refuting a scientific theory. A single observation might justify the former, but the data wouldn't be rich enough to support the kind of exploratory analysis that might suggest a plausible alternative, had none previously been entertained. And to get from a theoretical prediction to a number on paper representing a relevant observation requires a host of auxiliary theories, including mundane ones about the functioning of measurement apparatus & the reliability of observers, any one of which might be asked to take the fall.

Comment: I was trying with these comments to explore a bit the nature of your question. If any of them have succeeded at all in exemplifying the kind of answer you're looking for, could you please edit the question to make it clearer? Else I fear it'll never be answered.

Comment: @Scortchi thanks you for your comments. I will try to rephrase my question.